# Problema con la api google-map en react Esta página no puede cargar Google Maps correctamente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

**hola, en mi aplicación no se muestra el google map que ya previamente he configurado y suscripto. Sale un mensaje que dice: "esta [image: Esta página no puede cargar Google Maps correctamente.]página no puede cargar gooogle map correctamente"**

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Eso ocurre desde hace mucho, y es porque los de google maps cambiaron su política y ahora no dejan que usemos los maps libremente, quieren que nos registremos y hasta cobrarnos supongo. Busca alternativas, que las hay (yo me cambié a [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) que tampoco esta mal y no te cobran a menos que tengas un transito grande).

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @masterguru, necesitas ir a tu consola de desarrollador en Google y habilitar la `Javascript for Maps` API y de hecho te van a pedir que ingreses una tarjeta de crédito para poder usar esa API. Tienen `free trial` por tres meses though.